# Evaluate $\int_0^2\int_{y/2}^1{\frac{y^2}{1+x^4}}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

So I simplified it to $\int_0^2\int_{y/2}^1{\frac{1}{1+x^4}y^2}\,dx\,dy$

Then integrated, and got $\int_0^2(\frac{\ln(1+x^4)}{4x^3}y^2)_{y/2}^1\,dy$

Then I got: $\int_0^2((\frac{\ln(1)}{4}y^2)-(\frac{\ln(1+(\frac{y}{2})^4)}{4(y/2)^3}y^2))\,dy$

And then I figured, I must be going wrong somewhere....

I think it was in my ingration... Please someone help me!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29

The second step you posted seems to be incorrect. Try fixing that by keeping y constant and then integrating.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{1+x^4}\,dx \neq \frac{\ln(1+x^4)}{4x^3}$. (If you don't believe it, try to differentiate the RHS ;))

Answer (score 1):

By setting $y=2t$ then switching the order of integration we have:
$$ I = 8\int_{0}^{1}\int_{t}^{1}\frac{t^2}{1+x^4}\,dx\,dt=8\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1+x^4}\,dt\,dx $$
from which:
$$ I = \frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\,dx = \frac{2}{3}\left.\log(1+x^4)\right|_{0}^{1}=\color{red}{\frac{\log 4}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by changing the order of integration.
We have our area of integration:

$$ \Omega = \left\{ \frac{y}{2} \lt x \lt 1, 0  < y < 2\right\}$$

If you draw this out on a piece of paper, you have a shaded triangle under the line $ y = x/2$. You can see if you re-write this area in terms of x and y the original $\Omega$ is equivalent to:

$$ \Omega = \{ 0<x<1, 0<y<2x\}$$

This changes our integral bounds to:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2x}\frac{y^{2}}{1+x^4}\,dy\,dx$$
$$=\frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}dx$$

Which then evaluates to $\dfrac{2\log(2)}{3}$